# i keep get this "error C2059" C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am getting this error

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'if'
```

This is my code

```
// N.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    int x,y,n,i,m;
    std::cout<<"please enter a number";
    i=0;
    std::cin>>n;
    for (x=1;x=n;x++)
        for (y=1;y=n;y++)
        if (x=y) m=x;
        else;
    while (x!=y) ;
    do
    {
        if (x>y) x=x-y;
        else y=y-x;
        m=x;
    }
    if (m=1) i=i+1;
    std::cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

what is the problem ?

I am using microsoft visual studio 2008

Comment: It might be a good idea to look up the syntax for just about everything you have there. Hint: it's either `while( cond ) { .. }` or `do { ... } while( cond )`.

Comment: ... also it's `if (x==y)` not `if (x=y)` and similar for `if (m=1)`...

Comment: Why do you have an empty `else`? Why aren’t you indenting?

Comment: Use braces, { }, after each `for`, `if`, and `while`.  The braces are your friends.  They will help promote good quality code with less bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after the `do { ... }` the compiler is expecting a condition:

```
do
{
    if (x>y) x=x-y;
    else y=y-x;
    m=x;
} while (condition);
```

In addition, your code seems to be not correct at all. For instance, your `if (x=y)` condition may be like this: `if (x==y)`, and other...

Comment: ohh..
thanks man

yeah i know
i'm new to this kind of programming

thanks a lot

Comment: :) you are welcome. Try to read your code carefully trying to understand whats is doing, check syntax, and go step by step! Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Although it looks like it should be `while`, not `do...while`.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your `for` statements.
Use `==` for comparison, not `=` which is assignment.
Also, use `<` or `<=` as comparison.  The `==` condition may be skipped over in loops.

A suggestion to help prevent these issues in the future:  Use '{' and '}' with `for`, `if`, `else` and `while`.

For example:

```
for (x=1;x=n;x++)
{  // Insert this line.
    for (y=1;y=n;y++)
    {  // Insert this line.
        if (x=y)
        {
           m=x;
        }
        else
        {
           ;
        }
    } // End of for y
}  // End of for x
```

The braces and indentation help spot errors during code reviews.  Most coding styles demand the braces, even for single statements.

Also, use spaces to make code more readable.  They don't impact the build time or code generation, but really help when reading the code:
`for (x = 1; x <= n; x++)`